# Py Ephem Forumula for Local Sidereal Time for an Observer

Tags: pyephem

I am trying to calculate the uncertainty in the calculation of Local Sidereal Time using Pyephem, when I have many observation points with longitudes and timestamps with uncertainty.

What forumula does the observer.sidereal_time() use? Or in which .c file in libastro-3.7.5 is the LST calculation found?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `sidereal_time()` calculation calls `now_lst()` which you can find here:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/master/libastro-3.7.6/misc.c#L162

It only calls a few other functions, all of which should be described either directly in `misc.c` or in one of the nearby `.c` files there in the same directory.